# Run a Laravel Application With or Without a Key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, web-applications

I need a way to run a Laravel application in a client-server environment with a unique key or license key. If the client doesn't have a key, they cannot run this application. Even if they cannot break the code functionality in the source code, please help.

Comment: There is no way this can be achieved. PHP is not even a binary, you can just edit the files and remove the restriction. And binaries themselves are not safe either...

Comment: is there any way to keep some file in my server and run in client server?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the customer has access to the source code, they will always be able to bypass the license key check, however complex you will make it. PHP by default is not a compiled language and thus your requirement is not supported by the underlying architecture that Laravel is built on.

Having said that, there are third party compilers for PHP. Maybe they would be worth checking out, or consider using a solution that allows for compiling the source code - Java, .NET. Or, if that is an option, host the solution yourself, and let the customer be just a user/client of your hosted solution.

Comment: is there any way to keep some important file in my server and run in client server?

Comment: I suggest you look for a different programming language, PHP was not built for what you are looking for. It's probably not impossible to solve your problem, but you are going to be shoehorning the architecture to a solution and it should work the other way round.

Comment: development proccess of application is already done. i am not able to change programming language. thank you by the way.

Comment: I always hate that term "PHP was not built for that".  It's general purpose.  Can't you put a Laravel gate or policy in place over certain routes that would restrict the user if  their user does not have an active key / license in place?  Maybe a column on the user db with key / license etc and if it has a value it is valid (very crude).

Comment: That would be a good solution, provided that no-one has access to the source code to bypass the licensing restrictions. Part of the original question, however, states: "Even if they cannot break the code functionality in the source code".

Comment: Other languages like C# are by no means more secure in regards to licensing. You can still intercept requests to a license server. Or decompile the sources and change the code (actually **a lot** easier as it sounds). What's on the clients' computer _is already lost_.